# Can I check if a Apple watch is connected?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I would like to adjust the notification (make it shorter) when a watch is connected for the 'static' notification.

Is this possible?

-> So I'm not asking how to know when there is a disconnect with my app, I just want to know if my notifications will go to a watch or not (with or without a whatchkit app).

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the other question is about asking this on the watch, this question is about asking this in the app.